# UIImagePickerController allowsEditing=YES Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uiimagepickercontroller

I am still having this issue with the uiimagepickercontroller. It is supposed to be straight forward, but I still can't figure it out. Or maybe Im going in the wrong direction.

I call the imagepicker so that user can load a photo from camera roll/photo album/take a photo from camera. This part is fine.

It becomes weird when i set allowsEditing to YES. the didiFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate returns an NSDictionary *info with BOTH the editedImage and originalImage in it, even when user did NOT crop the image shown in the picker. So the problem is how can i detect whether the user cropped the image or not?

What I need for my app is the user is allowed to crop the image if he wishes to, but he also is given the choice NOT to crop, thus returning the original photo. Currently I am using a segmentedcontrol for user to pre-select before loading a photo, which I think is pretty inconvenience. And maybe some user does not understand it.

So how can I implement what I need without troubling the user so much?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you must edit the image if the edit controls are shown. I don't know of any way to get rid of the square.

However, if I'm wrong about that you could compare their sizes:

```
editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

if ((editedImage.size.width != originalImage.size.width) || (editedImage.size.height != originalImage.size.height)) {
    // The image has been edited
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your answer. Anyway, I think if I do that, it will always be TRUE. Because, for eg, say Im loading a portrait photo, when setting allowsEditing=YES, then the crop square is already there, thus editedImage will always return whatever that is inside that square, even if user has not cropped it. I thought of a way around this by perhaps asking the user whether he wants to crop the photo or not, and present the picker based on that input. Im out of other ideas.

Comment: You can ask afterwards since you have both images, but the editing square is likely to freak some people out. I think I'd use two different buttons like "Take a Photo" and "Take and Edit a Photo" instead of the segmented control, if you have room. The user is guaranteed to notice and intentionally choose the one they want.

Comment: On a user point of view, if the app ask for crop afterwards, it would be like asking the user about it twice. I think it would confuse the user. Your idea of Take a Photo and Take & Edit a Photo is ok. But at the moment I present an ACtionSheet to ask user whether or not he wants to crop the photo before presenting the UIImagePicker/Camera. This is because I already have 3 buttons (load from Camera Roll, Photo Albums and Take A camera). Anyway thanks for your replies I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: An action sheet is a good choice, too. My concern with the UI was the segmented control, which I think would be non-obvious to most users.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this.. it will automatically return the proper image, cropped or uncropped... and you still have all the info just incase :)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
```